# Drawing a pattern using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw a pattern of dots within a square. I have managed to draw the pattern, however there is a gap in the middle of the square (caused due to the inversion of the x coordinates). How can I correct this error? I have tried to invert the range (instead of the x coordinates), but python does not accept this format.

```
import turtle

T = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.tracer(0,0)
T.speed(10)
T.pensize(3)

zoom = 40 

def verticalSaddle2(T,n,k):
   for j in range(((n+1)//2),n+1):
          
    for i in range(1,(n+1)//2):
     
        if k <= 1 :
            return()

        else:
                        
                            T.penup()
                            T.setpos((j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                            T.pendown()
                            

                            T.dot(k)
                            k=k-2

    for i in range(((n+1)//2),n+1):
     
        if k <= 1 :
            return()
        else:
                        
                            T.penup()
                            T.setpos((j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                            T.pendown()
                            

                            T.dot(k)
                            k=k+2

 k=10
 n=7


 verticalSaddle2(T,n,k)

def verticalSaddle3(T,n,k):
for j in range(1,((n+1)//2)):
    
            for i in range(1,(n+1)//2):
             
                if k <= 1 :
                    return()

                else:
                                
                                    T.penup()
                                    T.setpos((-j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                                    T.pendown()
                                    

                                    T.dot(k)
                                    k=k-2

            for i in range(((n+1)//2),n+1):
             
                if k <= 1 :
                    return()
                else:
                                
                                    T.penup()
                                    T.setpos((-j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                                    T.pendown()
                                    

                                    T.dot(k)
                                    k=k+2
        
k=12
n=7
            
verticalSaddle3(T, n, k)

turtle.update()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: How about [this fixed code](https://cutt.ly/lgjkNuF) ? Fixed only ranges for `j` loop in both saddle functions. Resulting image [here](https://i.imgur.com/gDVSrkx.png).

Comment: Basically your `j` loop should be for same range from `0` to `(n+1)//2`. One function draws for positive `x` another one for negative `x` of same range.

Comment: OK, I'll post this code as answer then if it solved your task!

Comment: To have a decremanting range, you have to specify a negative increment. Try for example `range(10, 0, -1)` and see [documentation on `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Comment: @Grace500 I've also posted [simplified version of code](https://tio.run/##3ZNBbsMgEEX3c4pZQk1i7FSqFNWnqC9ghUlLSABh0qq5vIvjxE1qd9VdZ8N8mHnAF/jP@Obsquv0wbsQMR5D3BNAjdUlX9bngXG46BiaDQUmheRQL1tPpJhcyqJXnmyrT8RWHODk3CFRHiUCKNriO4WoN83@pVEq8WqBVqCRfA2YYusC7lBbDI19JbZgzGYFxzzHkmOGhcCbiaGlD5N2MHKUQ4yyh@pvaCHOjDy/JeBds94m5HOFBa5/QBEDJQdsMuJuhfYtTWtnj3ONs09Hn0jTlZaidy1jO/6AvYPp3prjkPN5knIfdoYFM9XKRWampaYyixJ@s42Nrok@@ZN1/9C5LDlnqqIEWz0BTF65Fant@neOXjXx5i8pZ3vVdV8) in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414118/941531) that has just one drawing function ranging `j` from `-(n+1)//2` to `(n+1)//2`.

Comment: @Grace500 Or [even much more simpler](https://tio.run/##ZZDRbsIwDEXf8xX3MYEU2jJp0qT9RX@gImEEVjtKU03j5zu3dKIIv9i@8rGuHX/zmekwjqGLnDLykPK3V6rB51Lvmjlpo5Y@p/boky5taVSzi576cPP6YJS6MXfCvZVQyvkT@tY5IRsLsriaDwWJEydcEAippS@vC61pWxns96gNtqgsVsId@cfCA5MxmqZXE1PMfoYoZp/V3ufIvb5gg8mklVX3yrzijn/oZYHjrK8oUAvXBdJB6tlDgWDk9Mep7xZVLcryrSG6Nq@@55imbhz/AA) variant of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to draw a dot painting of uniform circles filled into a square (ala Damien Hirst), here's the code. You can change the dimensions by changing the range function on the for loops accordingly. The colors are added at random, so you can ignore the colors, or just make them black, for the pattern.

```
import turtle as tim
from turtle import Screen
import random

tim.colormode(255)

color_list = [(25, 108, 164), (194, 38, 81), (238, 161, 49), (234, 215, 85), (226, 237, 228), (223, 137, 176),
              (144, 108, 56), (102, 197, 219), (206, 166, 29), (20, 57, 132), (214, 73, 90), (239, 89, 50),
              (141, 208, 227), (118, 192, 140), (3, 186, 176), (106, 107, 199), (138, 29, 73), (4, 161, 86),
              (98, 51, 36), (22, 156, 210), (232, 165, 184), (175, 185, 221), (29, 90, 95), (233, 172, 161),
              (152, 213, 190), (242, 205, 8), (89, 48, 31), (39, 46, 81), (26, 97, 94)]

tim.penup()


def dot_painting():
    count = 0
    for _ in range(10):
        for step in range(10):
            tim.dot(30, random.choice(color_list))
            tim.forward(35)
            if step == 9:
                count += 1
                if count % 2 != 0:
                    turn_left()
                else:
                    turn_right()


def turn_right():
    tim.dot(30, random.choice(color_list))
    tim.right(90)
    tim.forward(35)
    tim.right(90)


def turn_left():
    tim.dot(30, random.choice(color_list))
    tim.left(90)
    tim.forward(35)
    tim.left(90)


dot_painting()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your function draws left part of picture for negative `x`, another function almost same picture for right part for positive `x`, both parts are just mirrored versions of another part. `x` is handled by `j` loop. In order to draw same left and right picture without gap your both `j` loops should be fixed to be in same range, from `0` to `(n+1)//2`. Resulting fixed code below:

```
import turtle

T = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.tracer(0,0)
T.speed(0.01)
T.pensize(3)

zoom = 40 

def verticalSaddle2(T,n,k):
    for j in range(0,(n+1) // 2):
              
        for i in range(1,(n+1)//2):
         
            if k <= 1 :
                return()

            else:
                            
                T.penup()
                T.setpos((j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                T.pendown()
                

                T.dot(k)
                k=k-2

        for i in range(((n+1)//2),n+1):
         
            if k <= 1 :
                return()
            else:
                            
                T.penup()
                T.setpos((j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                T.pendown()
                

                T.dot(k)
                k=k+2

k=10
n=7


verticalSaddle2(T,n,k)

def verticalSaddle3(T,n,k):
    for j in range(0,((n+1)//2)):
        
        for i in range(1,(n+1)//2):
         
            if k <= 1 :
                return()

            else:
                            
                T.penup()
                T.setpos((-j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                T.pendown()
                

                T.dot(k)
                k=k-2

        for i in range(((n+1)//2),n+1):
         
            if k <= 1 :
                return()
            else:
                            
                T.penup()
                T.setpos((-j)* zoom, (i) * zoom)
                T.pendown()
                

                T.dot(k)
                k=k+2
        
k=12
n=7
            
verticalSaddle3(T, n, k)

turtle.update()
turtle.done()
```

Resulting image output below:

[image]

Your code can be simplified to have just one drawing function which draws `x` (`j`) in range from `-(n + 1) / 2` to `(n + 1) / 2`. [Simplified code is here](https://tio.run/##3ZNBbsMgEEX3c4pZQk1i7FSqFNWnqC9ghUlLSABh0qq5vIvjxE1qd9VdZ8N8mHnAF/jP@Obsquv0wbsQMR5D3BNAjdUlX9bngXG46BiaDQUmheRQL1tPpJhcyqJXnmyrT8RWHODk3CFRHiUCKNriO4WoN83@pVEq8WqBVqCRfA2YYusC7lBbDI19JbZgzGYFxzzHkmOGhcCbiaGlD5N2MHKUQ4yyh@pvaCHOjDy/JeBds94m5HOFBa5/QBEDJQdsMuJuhfYtTWtnj3ONs09Hn0jTlZaidy1jO/6AvYPp3prjkPN5knIfdoYFM9XKRWampaYyixJ@s42Nrok@@ZN1/9C5LDlnqqIEWz0BTF65Fant@neOXjXx5i8pZ3vVdV8) .

It is possible to simplify even more to have very short code like next:

```
import turtle

T = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.tracer(0,0)
T.pensize(3)

zoom = 40 

def saddle(T, n, k):
    for j in range(-((n + 1) // 2) + 1, (n + 1) // 2):
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            T.penup()
            T.setpos(j * zoom, i * zoom)
            T.pendown()
            T.dot(k - 2 * (min(i - 1, n - i) + (n + 1) // 2 - 1 - abs(j)))

saddle(T, 7, 16)

turtle.update()
turtle.done()
```

Comment: I've run all three of your example solutions and *none* appear to generate the desired image.  Take a close look at the ouput of each.

Comment: @cdlane Author of question approved that in fact my drawing was correct and what he wanted. On my machine first code draws [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6FS.png) and that is what author wants. The picture shown in the question post is not the desired output but what author's code show currently, and he wants output [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6FS.png).

Comment: I based my comment on your columns 4 & 5 above being identical though in the image the OP posted, they are different.  In your alternate solutions, adjacent rows are identical, unlike the OP's image.  And they don't generate the same image as above.

Comment: Although I changed my code in the manner that you suggested , in the code provided above ,columns 4 and 5 are identical which should not be the case .However , changing the j loops in the code that I posted works !

Comment: @Grace500 Yes, that was just an idea by me that `j` was in wrong range in both loops, so the idea was just to modify it a bit, although probably some small tweaking is needed. BTW, simplified code at the very end of my answer draws everything correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're making this problem more difficult than necessary.  I would first get the code to simply draw a grid of uniform dots.  Then modify the code to size the dots based on their position in the grid.  Something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

DISTANCE = 40

def saddle(t, n, minimum=1):
    assert n % 2 == 1, "n should be odd"

    t.penup()

    for x in range(-n // 2 + 1, n // 2 + 1):
        t.setx(x * DISTANCE)

        for y in range(-n // 2 + 1, n // 2 + 1):
            t.sety(y * DISTANCE)
            t.dot(2 * (minimum + abs(x) + abs(y)))

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

saddle(turtle, 7)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

I've made my code insist on an odd number for `n`, otherwise the pattern isn't symmetric.